# having syntax error trying to use on duplicate

Tags: executemany

```
sql_insert_query = "insert into TABLE1 (building, course, description, course_type, course_type_desc, dual_credit) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE building = VALUES(building), course = VALUES(course), description = VALUES(description), course_type = VALUES(course_type), course_type_desc = VALUES(course_type_desc), dual_credit = VALUES(dual_credit);"

cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, listCourse)
```

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
>   (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

This one below only works, but adds duplicate when running again.

```
"insert into TABLE1 (building, course, description, course_type, course_type_desc, dual_credit) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by tile with tuple

listCourse = numpy.tile(courses, 2)
listCourse = map(tuple,numpy.tile(courses, 2))

Answer (score 0):

I tied '%s' this did not work so I am using '?'